# What do backticks do in R?

Tags: r, syntax, backticks

I'm trying to understand what backticks do in R.

From what I can tell, this is not explained in the `?Quotes` documentation page for R.

For example, at the R console:

```
"[["
# [1] "[["
`[[`
# .Primitive("[[")
```

It seem to be returning the equivalent to:

```
get("[[")
```

Comment: help("`")  might be in order

Comment: `help("\`")` brings up the same doc page as `?Quotes`, which was not entirely clear

Comment: missed that in the q. apologies. but it's a decent explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A pair of backticks is a way to refer to names or combinations of symbols that are otherwise reserved or illegal. Reserved are words like `if` are part of the language, while illegal includes non-syntactic combinations like `c a t`. These two categories, reserved and illegal, are referred to in R documentation as `non-syntactic names`.

Thus,

```
`c a t` <- 1 # is valid R
```

and

```
> `+` # is equivalent to typing in a syntactic function name
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("+")
```

As a commenter mentioned, `?Quotes` does contain some information on the backtick, under `Names and Identifiers:`

> Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (`.`) and the underscore. They must not start with a digit nor underscore, nor with a period followed by a digit. Reserved words are not valid identifiers.
>
> The definition of a *letter* depends on the current locale, but only ASCII digits are considered to be digits.
>
> Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used directly in R code. Almost always, other names can be used provided they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick (`` ` ``), and `deparse` will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to a name). One place where backticks may be essential is to delimit variable names in formulae: see `formula`

This prose is a little hard to parse. What it means is that for R to parse a token as a name, it must be 1) a sequence of letters digits, the period and underscores, that 2) is not a reserved word in the language. Otherwise, to be parsed as a name, backticks must be used.

Also check out `?Reserved`:

> Reserved words outside quotes are always parsed to be references to the objects linked to in the 'Description', and hence they are not allowed as syntactic names (see `make.names`). They are allowed as non-syntactic names, e.g.inside backtick quotes.

In addition, Advanced R has some examples of how backticks are used in [expressions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html), [environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html), and [functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html).

Answer (score 11):

Here is an incomplete answer using improper vocabulary: backticks can indicate to R that you are using a function in a non-standard way. For instance, here is a use of `[[`, the list subsetting function:

```
temp <- list("a"=1:10, "b"=rnorm(5))
```

extract element one, the usual way

```
temp[[1]]
```

extract element one using the `[[` function

```
`[[`(temp,1)
```

Answer (score 9):

They are equivalent to verbatim. For example... try this:

```
df <- data.frame(20a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
```

gives error

```
df <- data.frame(`20a`=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
```

doesn't give error