# Inverted commas in R

Tags: r

I’m very new so pardon me for asking if this is like basics. I have googled but cannot seem to find a clear explanation. What’s the difference between ‘ and “ and ` (the key to the left of 1 on the keyboard). Google tells me ‘ and “ have no difference but nothing about [the sign]. I’m looking at various scripts to understand them. ‘ or “ can be used interchangeably depending on the writer style. But I can’t figure out [the sign], and I cannot replace [the sign] with ‘ or “ in the code, if not I’ll get error. To me, they just seem to be indicating the words as strings? But the fact that I cannot replace [the sign] makes me wonder what is it?

Comment: The `\`` is a *backtick* - see some info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353174/r-encoding-ascii-backtick

Comment: See also `help("Quotes")`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I sort of understand already, so that person uses backtick cos the names have spaces in between. Will read up more as I learn. Now that I know it’s “backtick”, it’s easier to Google as well :)