# Calling variable named in number in model formula

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named "exposure" in long format. It has a CRP protein variable named "CRP" and 100 metabolites named as 1_T1, 2_T1, 3_T1, 4_T1 etc.

When I tried to do a simple linear regression with lm:

`lm(1_T1 ~ CRP, data = exposure)`

r returned `Error: unexpected input in "lm(1_"`

When I changed the metabolite names in the dataframe starting from alphabet such as m1_T1, m2_T2 etc, it works.

My question is: 
Is there a way calling variables named with number that will be treated correctly in the model formula in R, without resolving by changing the variable names?

I tried to use `"1_T1"` but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Jake

Comment: You could try backticks, but R has rules about what are syntactically valid names (all languages do). Probably best to just work within that.

Comment: Thanks Joran!  From your hints, I found this page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220823/what-do-backticks-do-in-r) that helps to explain what's the identifier requirement in R.  Naming variables with numeric starting is just a bad habit. I will rename them instead

Comment: If `i` and `j` are the response and independent variable column names or column numbers in `exposure` then lm( exposure[ c(i, j) ] )`  will work.  No formula is needed in that case.