# What is the difference between ` `, ' ' and " " in R language?

Tags: r, dplyr, quotations

In particular, when spreading a tibble, dplyr name the columns with ` ` (in case of strings or dates) and I noticed that it is not interchangeable with neither ' ' nor "".

After having spreaded a tibble I´ve ended up with names in the columns. And I was trying to filter with `` and it was not working.

```
pms$releases$date_201803$table_6443 %>% 
  filter( `Variável (Código)` == "8677", `Tipos de índice (Código)` %in% c("40311", "40312"))
```

But the alternative bellow works fine, and I was trying to understand the relation between the types of quotation.

```
colunas <- c("Variável (Código)", "Tipos de índice (Código)")

pms$releases$date_201803$table_6443 %>% 
  filter(!!as.name(colunas[1]) == "8677", !!as.name(colunas[2]) %in% c("40311", "40312"))
```

Comment: Maybe provide an example of the data you are spreading?

Comment: It's documented at the hard-to-find but sensibly-named `?Quotes`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What do backticks do in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36220823/903061)