# How can I assign rownames with `<-` while using a pipe `%>%`?

Tags: r, magrittr

We can assign the rownames of a data frame by using the `<-` operator with `rownames(df)` as below:

```
df<-data.frame(a=letters[1:5], b=1:5, c=LETTERS[1:5])
df
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df[,1] <- NULL
df
```

Above script will convert the first column to rowname, output as below:

```
df
  a b c
1 a 1 A
2 b 2 B
3 c 3 C
4 d 4 D
5 e 5 E

df
  b c
a 1 A
b 2 B
c 3 C
d 4 D
e 5 E
```

Is there a way to use pipe `%>%` to do it?

I tried `df %>% rownames(.) <- .[,1]` but failed.
The key issue is cannot use `<-` between `%>%`

Comment: I think you want `column_to_rownames` from the *tibble* package - https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html

Comment: it's simple function,is there a way not to use additional package?

Comment: `%>%` is useful to avoid nesting. It converts `foo(bar(baz(x)))` to `x %>% foo %>% bar %>% baz`. In your example, you start with `rownames(df) <- df[,1]`, which has no nesting. You cannot use `%>%` on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: @kittygirl - if you're using the `%>%`, I just assumed you're probably already using dplyr + tibble etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While the `<-` operator looks like something special, when used to replace `rownames()`, it’s actually a shortcut for the `` `rownames<-`() `` function, which you can just call directly in the pipe:

```
data.frame(a=letters[1:5], b=1:5, c=LETTERS[1:5]) %>%
    `rownames<-`(.[,1])

  a b c
a a 1 A
b b 2 B
c c 3 C
d d 4 D
e e 5 E
```

This is the function you’re actually always using when you assign rownames:

```
# When you write this
rownames(df) <- c(1:5)

# What R is actually doing is running this function:
`rownames<-`(df, c(1:5))
```

You can do the same thing with `` `colnames<-`() `` and `` `names<-`() `` as well

The backtick character (`` ` ``) defines something as a symbol, even if it otherwise contains characters that are illegal in a symbol. Enclosing it in backticks tells R that you are running a function called `rownames<-` and passing in `.[,1]` as an argument. Without it, R would stop reading the function name when it reaches the `<` sign, and look for the normal `rownames` function, which is not what we want here.

Read this question for more detail on the backtick syntax: [What do backticks do in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220823/what-do-backticks-do-in-r)

Comment: what's the usage of ` before and after `rownames<-`?

Comment: It treats `rownames<-` as an expression/function.
Whereas without the ` before and after, R would read `rownames`  `<-` ie assign something to object `rownames`.

Comment: Then, why add `()` around `.[,1]`?

Comment: Because `` `rownames<-`()`` is a function that takes arguments inside its parentheses, just like any other function.

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:5], b = 1:5, c = LETTERS[1:5])
df
```

```
> df
  a b c
1 a 1 A
2 b 2 B
3 c 3 C
4 d 4 D
5 e 5 E
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df1 <- df %>% 
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "a")
df1
```

```
> df1
  b c
a 1 A
b 2 B
c 3 C
d 4 D
e 5 E
```

Comment: Couldn't you have just used `var = "a"` and bypassed the `rename` call?

Comment: yeah, i could. I tried to make it clearer. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any additional package, you can achieve the same result by doing

```
df1 <- data.frame(df[-1], row.names = df[,1])
df1
#  b c
#a 1 A
#b 2 B
#c 3 C
#d 4 D
#e 5 E
```

and with `dplyr` you can probably just `pull` the values from the column to assign to `rownames`

```
library(dplyr)
rownames(df) <- df %>% pull(a)
```