# why do I not get the ordering in alphabetical order in my table, in R? Only with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, alphabetical

I am trying to arrange 'Smoking status' categories in alphabetical order.This shoudl be only with tidyverse.

This is what I have tried

```
smoking_gender_disch_piv_count_ren <- smoking_gender_disch_piv_count %>%
       dplyr::rename('Smoking Status' = smoking_status) %>%
       dplyr::arrange('Smoking status')
     smoking_gender_disch_piv_count_ren
```

As one can see, I do not get Current smoker first, and then ex smoker, etc. I thought arrange function in dplyr will do the trick. But it does not.

This is the data I have:

```
structure(list(smoking_status = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Ex smoker", 
"Current smoker", "Never smoked", "Unknown", "Non smoker - smoking history unknown"
), class = "factor"), Female = c(24.0601503759398, 9.02255639097744, 
35.3383458646617, 6.01503759398496, 25.5639097744361), Male = c(34.9753694581281, 
13.7931034482759, 23.6453201970443, 1.97044334975369, 25.615763546798
), NSTEMI = c(31.9078947368421, 12.5, 28.2894736842105, 3.28947368421053, 
24.0131578947368), STEMI = c(18.75, 6.25, 28.125, 6.25, 40.625
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Have you tried re-ordering the factor levels, or coercing to character?

Comment: Re-ordering? How ?

Comment: In `arrange`, use backticks around Smoking Status rather than single quotes. On a standard American keyboard, the backtick is the key in the upper left corner. With single quotes, R treats it as a character string, rather than as a column name in your data.

Comment: @eipi10 did try both - "Smoking status" and `Smoking Status` in arrange function and does not work

Comment: @GaB Please use `dput()` to provide a reproducible version of your `smoking_gender_disch_piv_count` dataset.  If I had to guess, your problem is that `\`Smoking Status\`` is a `factor` (not a `character` string), where `"Current smoker"` comes before `"Ex smoker"`.  Maybe try `dplyr::arrange(as.character(\`Smoking Status\`))`?

Comment: @Greg, you're right! Did it.  Tried passing as.character and it did not work.

Comment: @Greg, funny enough, I passed dplyr::arrange(as.character(smokig_status)) and it worked! Oddly enough the white spaces. Probably this is what eipi10 referred to?

Comment: @Greg please post it as an asnwer and then explain the reason? Weird!!

Comment: @GaB You misspelled `\`Smoking Status\`` as `\`Smoking status\``

Comment: Just try arrange(`Smoking Status`) and it should work the problem in your example is that you had status not Status (S capital).

Comment: I have actually corrected it, and it does not solve the issue. I believe the "Smoking status" doesn not do the trick, rather "smoking_status". I could be the white space in between? Still someone shoudl post as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from misspelling `'Smoking Status'` as `'Smoking status'`, you ran into two other problems.

## Variable Names vs. Strings

We use single (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) to designate **strings**: `'my string'` or `"my string"`. However, to designate (unusual) **variable names** (symbols) with spaces in them, [we use backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229703) (`` ` ``): `` `my variable` ``.  Since it's a pain to type those backticks, we typically use underscores (`_`) rather than spaces in variable names.

When **(re)naming** columns, `character` strings are as good as symbols.  That is

```
  # ... %>%
  dplyr::rename('Smoking Status' = smoking_status) # %>% ...
  #             |--------------|
  #             character string
```

is equivalent to

```
  # ... %>%
  dplyr::rename(`Smoking Status` = smoking_status) # %>% ...
  #             |--------------|
  #                  symbol
```

**However**, when performing vectorized operations with `mutate()` or `filter()` or `arrange()`, any string will be treated as simply a scalar `character` value.  That is

```
  # ... %>%
  mutate(test = 'Smoking Status') # %>% ...
  #             |--------------|
  #             character string
```

will **not** copy the `` `Smoking Status` `` column (a `factor`)

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  ... test                                
  ... <fct>                               
1 ... Ex smoker                           
2 ... Current smoker                      
3 ... Never smoked                        
4 ... Unknown                             
5 ... Non smoker - smoking history unknown
```

but rather give you a (`character`) column filled with the literal string `'Smoking Status'`:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  ... test          
  ... <chr>         
1 ... Smoking Status
2 ... Smoking Status
3 ... Smoking Status
4 ... Smoking Status
5 ... Smoking Status
```

Similarly, your

```
  # ... %>%
  dplyr::arrange('Smoking Status')
  #                       |----|
  #      Corrected typo: 'status'.
```

does not sort on the `` `Smoking Status` `` column, but rather on a (temporary) column filled with the string `'Smoking Status'`. Since everything in that column is the same, no rearranging occurs at all, and the `smoking_gender_disch_piv_count` dataset remains unchanged.

### Fix

To fix *this particular* issue, use:

```
  # ... %>%
  dplyr::arrange(`Smoking Status`)
```

## Strings vs. Factors

Even after fixing the issue above, you'll still have a problem. Your `Smoking Status` column is a `factor`

```
[1] Ex smoker                            Current smoker                       Never smoked                         Unknown                              Non smoker - smoking history unknown
Levels: Ex smoker Current smoker Never smoked Unknown Non smoker - smoking history unknown
```

so when you sort on this column, it follow the ordering of the `factor` levels, which are visibly **not** in alphabetical order.

### Fix

To sort by alphabetical order, use the `character` form of the `` `Smoking Status` `` column:

```
  # ... %>%
  dplyr::arrange(as.character(`Smoking Status`))
```

## Solution

Given the `smoking_gender_disch_piv_count` dataset you reproduced

```
smoking_gender_disch_piv_count <-
  structure(list(smoking_status = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Ex smoker", "Current smoker", "Never smoked", "Unknown", "Non smoker - smoking history unknown"), class = "factor"),
                 Female = c(24.0601503759398, 9.02255639097744, 35.3383458646617, 6.01503759398496, 25.5639097744361),
                 Male = c(34.9753694581281, 13.7931034482759, 23.6453201970443, 1.97044334975369, 25.615763546798),
                 NSTEMI = c(31.9078947368421, 12.5, 28.2894736842105, 3.28947368421053, 24.0131578947368),
                 STEMI = c(18.75, 6.25, 28.125, 6.25, 40.625)),
            row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

the following `dplyr` workflow

```
smoking_gender_disch_piv_count_ren <- smoking_gender_disch_piv_count %>%
  dplyr::rename(`Smoking Status` = smoking_status) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(as.character(`Smoking Status`))
```

will give you your desired results for `smoking_gender_disch_piv_count_ren`

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  `Smoking Status`                     Female  Male NSTEMI STEMI
  <fct>                                 <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Current smoker                         9.02 13.8   12.5   6.25
2 Ex smoker                             24.1  35.0   31.9  18.8 
3 Never smoked                          35.3  23.6   28.3  28.1 
4 Non smoker - smoking history unknown  25.6  25.6   24.0  40.6 
5 Unknown                                6.02  1.97   3.29  6.25
```

while still preserving the `factor` information in `` `Smoking Status` ``.