# How to escape invalid/syntactically ambiguous term names in `reformulate`?

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I use `reformulate` to construct formulas involving a set of indicators for Reddit usernames.  Unfortunately, `reformulate` seems to concatenate a string out of the passed term names and parse it, which leads to some weird problems for terms that are valid usernames, but not valid identifiers:

```r
> reformulate(c("123a", "x"), "y")
Error in str2lang(termtext) : <text>:1:4: unexpected symbol
1: 123a
       ^
```

Even worse, something like this can happen:

```r
> reformulate(c("x", "a-b-1", "z"), "y")
y ~ x + a - b - 1 + z
```

How can I remedy this using some kind of "escape mechanism", and without resorting to string processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote every term name using backticks, to specify each username as a separate [non-syntactic name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229703/1346276):

```r
> paste0("`", c("123a", "a-b-1", "z"), "`")
[1] "`123a`"  "`a-b-1`" "`z`" 
> reformulate(paste0("`", c("123a", "a-b-1", "z"), "`"), "y")
y ~ `123a` + `a-b-1` + z
```

The backticks don't become part of the term names.  As you can see with `z`, syntactic names stay unchanged.