# Can't `filter()` a numeric column even though `r` says it is a number (`typeof()` is "double")

Tags: r, csv, dplyr, qualtrics, readr

I am new to `r` but I have looked around and tried everything I can think of. Here is the step by step:

- Pulled data from Qualtrics into csv
- Used `read_csv()` (much harder with `read.csv()`) to remove all (3 in this case) header rows and saved one to `names()`
- Pulled in data with `read_csv` and assigned header with `names()`
- Filtering `Duration (in seconds)` based upon its numerical value does not work. That is, `filter('Duration (in seconds)' == 0) yields a dataframe with no observations.

I have:

- Successfully filtered other numerical columns
- Verified that `typeof(test$'Duration (in seconds)')` is "double"
- Verified that `read_csv()` imports 'Duration (in seconds)' as double (i.e., `'Duration (in seconds)' = col_double()`)

Sample code

```
df_names <- read_csv("file.csv", n_max=0) %>% names()
test <- read_csv("file.csv", skip=3, col_names=df_names, trim_ws = T)
test2 <- test %>% filter('Duration (in seconds)' == 0) #no rows but should be 6
test2 <- test %>% filter('Duration (in seconds)' > 0) #all rows but should be 3
```

Data: [file.csv](https://ufile.io/ww5d1age)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your quotes with backticks when referencing your variable name:

```
test2 <- test %>% filter(`Duration (in seconds)` == 0) #no rows but should be 6
test2 <- test %>% filter(`Duration (in seconds)` > 0) #all rows but should be 3
```

Explanation: quotation marks denote strings in R; since your column is not a string, your original filter command doesn't select your desired column, and therefore won't return any rows in your filtered dataframe.

Backticks have [a few uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220823/what-do-backticks-do-in-r) in R, but one of them is to give you a way of referring to names that are otherwise non-syntactic. We need to use backticks in this example because your column name has spaces in it. If we didn't, R would assume that each word in `Duration (in seconds)` was a separate object, which would be non-syntactic and throw an error.

Comment: Thank you! @Rory S, would you mind explaining why the column name causes problems here and why backticks solve it? I would like to edit and re-tag or link to a duplicate answer so that others can find the problem, but I don't know what to call my problem.  Certainly, with a fix that simple it is a common issue.

Comment: @BobIsahofferer no problem! Just edited my answer to add an explanation of why backticks work here - hopefully that's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Using `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(test, `Duration (in seconds)` == 0)
```