# How to prevent `...` to disappear inside of deparse(substitute(x))

Tags: r, function, parsing

**Short version**

Consider this function:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  deparse(substitute(x))
}
```

Why does the function remove the ` if nothing else than one variable name is added? See here:

```
my_fun(`bad name`)
"bad name"
my_fun(`bad name` - 1)
"`bad name` - 1"
```

---

**Long version**

I wrote a simple function that takes a dataframe and does some transformation with choosen columns. This is the function:

```
my_fun <- function(data, transform){
  transform <- deparse(substitute(transform))
  transform <- unlist(strsplit(transform, "\\+"))
  out <- do.call("cbind.data.frame", lapply(transform, function(transform_i){
    eval(parse(text= transform_i), data)
  }))
  names(out) <- transform
  return(out)
}
```

With this function we can do stuff like this:

```
# Create data.
df <- data.frame(matrix(rep(1:4, 2), ncol= 2))
names(df) <- c("good_name", "bad name")

# Transform data with function.
my_fun(df, sqrt(good_name) + sqrt(`bad name`) - 1)
  sqrt(good_name)   sqrt(`bad name`) - 1
1         1.000000             0.0000000
2         1.414214             0.4142136
3         1.732051             0.7320508
4         2.000000             1.0000000
```

But the function fails if we enter a name containig a white space like here: my_fun(df, `bad name`). I noticed that `deparse(substitute(transform))` removes the ` if I make no transformation. See here:

```
my_fun <- function(data, transform){
  deparse(substitute(transform))
}
my_fun(df, `bad name`)
"bad name"
my_fun(df, `bad name` -1)
"`bad name` - 1"
```

How can I prevent `deparse(substitute(transform))` removing the `?

I know that there are many ways out there to transform dataframe like my function does. For example, we could use with(df, `bad name` -1) and with(df, `bad name`) here. But that is not the question.

Comment: From `?deparse`: the default for the backtick option is not to quote single symbols but only composite expressions. This is a compromise to avoid breaking existing code. Have a look at `substitute(\`bad_name\`)` vs `deparse(subsitutte(\`bad_name\`))` vs `deparse(substitute(\`bad_name\`), backtick = T)`. However, when I run `my_fun(df, \`bad name\`)` the result is fine.

Comment: @DonaldSeinen Running my_fun(df, \`bad name\`) for the long version `my_fun` results in this error for me: Error in parse(text = transform_i) : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
1: bad name
^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help file `?default`: *The default for the backtick option is not to quote single symbols but only composite expressions*. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220823/what-do-backticks-do-in-r) hints at looking at the `?Quotes` help file - we can escape backticks using a backslash if needed.

In this example, one may try setting the backtick argument of the `deparse` function to `TRUE`. To compare different approaches, and how combinations are deparsed, consider the following situations:

```
substitute(`bad name`)
#> `bad name`

deparse(substitute(`bad name`))
#> [1] "bad name"

deparse(substitute(`bad name`), backtick = T)
#> [1] "`bad name`"

# and see this fail:
substitute(`bad name)

# and this return
deparse(
  deparse(substitute(`bad name`))
)
#> "\"bad name\""

deparse(substitute(
  `deparse(substitute(bad name))`
))
#> [1] "deparse(substitute(bad name))"

deparse(substitute(
  `deparse(substitute(`bad name`))`
))
#> Error: unexpected symbol in:
#> "deparse(substitute(
#>  `deparse(substitute(`bad"
#> > ))
#> Error: unexpected ')' in ")"

# but
deparse(substitute(
  `deparse(substitute(\`bad name\`))`
))
#> [1] "deparse(substitute(`bad name`))"
```

If the intent is to enforce character names, have a look at `deparse1` for [R4.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.0.0/NEWS.R-4.0.0.html) (April 2020) and later.