# Can you call a function argument within a text string?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm just wondering if you can call function variable within a string of text so for example instead of this:

```
welcome <- function(name,age,location) {paste("Welcome! Your name is", name,"you are",age,"years old and live in", location)}

welcome("Emma","26","UK")
```

Something like this:

```
welcome <- function(name,age,location) {paste("Welcome! Your name is **name:** you are **age:** years old and live in **location:**")}

welcome(Emma,26,UK)
```

Comment: You can do this with e.g. `deparse(substitute(name))`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520772/in-r-how-to-get-an-objects-name-after-it-is-sent-to-a-function). But... you probably shouldn't. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a string formatting operator in R similar to Python's %?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085274/is-there-a-string-formatting-operator-in-r-similar-to-pythons)

Comment: I'm not actually trying to do anything I was just curious because there is a simple way to do this in SAS that I have used before and I was trying to find a way to do the same thing.

Comment: If this is for string building specifically, you might be interested in the [glue package](https://glue.tidyverse.org/)

Answer (score 6):

In general it is not idiomatic to program in this way in R. There are exceptions - you may wish to read the [Non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) chapter of Advanced R.

If you do need to do this, there are two ways that I'm familiar with: `deparse(substitute())` and [`match.call()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/match.call).

Firstly, `deparse(substitute())`:

```r
welcome2 <- function(name, age, location) {
    paste(
        "Welcome! Your name is",
        deparse(substitute(name)),
        "you are",
        age, # No need to deparse an integer
        "years old and live in",
        deparse(substitute(location))
    )
}

welcome2(Emma, 26, UK)
# [1] "Welcome! Your name is Emma you are 26 years old and live in UK"
```

However, this can [behave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904321/deparsesubstitute-returns-function-name-normally-but-function-code-when-cal) [surprisingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260900/how-to-prevent-to-disappear-inside-of-deparsesubstitutex).

Alternatively, you can use `match.call()`, which is much cleaner:

```r
welcome3 <- function(name, age, location) {
    args <- as.list(match.call())
    paste(
        "Welcome! Your name is",
        args$name,
        "you are",
        args$age,
        "years old and live in",
        args$location
    )
}

welcome3(Emma, 26, UK)
# [1] "Welcome! Your name is Emma you are 26 years old and live in UK"
```

One reason not to do this, though, is that these methods do not work if calling from another function. For example:

```r
welcome_wrapper3  <- function(name, age, location) {
    welcome3(name, age, location)
}

welcome_wrapper3(Emma, 26, UK)
# [1] "Welcome! Your name is name you are age years old and live in location"
```

You get the same result with both approaches. Additionally, if you want your function to evaluate your arguments, it will cause problems. Compare:

```r
welcome("Emma", 26-1, "UK")
# [1] "Welcome! Your name is Emma you are 25 years old and live in UK"
welcome3(Emma, 26-1, UK)
# [1] "Welcome! Your name is Emma you are - years old and live in UK"  "Welcome! Your name is Emma you are 26 years old and live in UK"
# [3] "Welcome! Your name is Emma you are 1 years old and live in UK"
```

So generally this is not something you should do unless there's a very good reason.

#### Using `sprintf()`

You can also use `sprintf()` instead of `paste()`, as suggested in the comments by Roland, which arguably can make the code a little cleaner. You need to use `match.call()[-1]` to remove the first argument, which is the name of the function, i.e. `welcome4` in this case. You also need to use `as.character()` as `as.list(match.call())` returns a list of symbols, which you cannot supply directly to `sprintf()`.

```r
welcome4 <- function(name, age, location) {
    do.call(sprintf, c(
        "Welcome! Your name is %s you are %s years old and live in %s",
        lapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], as.character)
    ))
}

welcome4(Emma, 26, UK)
# [1] "Welcome! Your name is Emma you are 26 years old and live in UK"
```

Comment: Use `sprintf` instead of `paste`. It also gives you some formatting options.

Comment: @Roland thanks I've added an example with `sprintf()`

Answer (score 2):

Another option, using [`glue`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/) and [`substitute()`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute):

```
welcome <- function(name,age,location) glue::glue("Welcome! Your name is {substitute(name)} you are {age} years old and live in {substitute(location)}")
```