# Extract operator `$( )` and non-syntactic names

Tags: r, list, function, scope

Say I have the following list (note the usage of [non-syntactic names](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic))

```
list <- list(A  = c(1,2,3),
            `2` = c(7,8,9))
```

So the following two way of parsing the list works:

```
`$`(list,A)
## [1] 1 2 3

`$`(list,`2`)
## [1] 7 8 9
```

However, this way to proceed fails.

```
id <- 2 
`$`(list,id)
## NULL
```

Could someone explain why the last way does not work and how I could fix it? Thank you.

Comment: This is because `list` (the object) does not have a variables named `id`. Try, ```list$id <- 2; 
`$`(list,id)```, it does work; or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Maël. This indeed works. However, as you mention, the object  `list` does not contain any variable called `id`, but the content of `id` is `2`, which is actually included in the list. So, I would like to extract `c(7,8,9)` somehow using another object (in this case, `id`). I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: It is clearer now yes. I think the question is not only relevant for non-syntactic names but also for syntactic ones, see ```id <- "A"; `$`(list,id)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` is a "computed index", which is not supported by the `$` operator. From `?Extract`:

> Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list.  The main difference is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[` does.  `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`.

If you have a computed index, then use `[[` to extract.

```r
l <- list(a = 1:3)
id <- "a"

l[[id]]
## [1] 1 2 3

`[[`(l, id) # the same
## [1] 1 2 3
```

If you insist on using the `$` operator, then you need to substitute the value of `id` in the `$` call, like so:

```r
eval(bquote(`$`(l, .(id))))
## [1] 1 2 3
```

It doesn't really matter whether `id` is non-syntactic:

```r
l <- list(`!@#$%^` = 1:3)
id <- "!@#$%^"

l[[id]]
## [1] 1 2 3

`[[`(l, id)
## [1] 1 2 3

eval(bquote(`$`(l, .(id))))
## [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I am also trying to get a better grasp of non-syntactic names. Unfortunately, more complex patterns of their use are hard to find. First, read `?Quotes` and [what backticks do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220823/what-do-backticks-do-in-r).

For the purpose of learning here is some code:

```r
list <- list(A  = c(1,2,3),
             `2` = c(7,8,9))

id <- 2 

id_backtics <- paste0("`", id,"`")

text <- paste0("`$`(list, ", id_backtics, ")")
text
#> [1] "`$`(list, `2`)"

eval(parse(text = text))
#> [1] 7 8 9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>