# What is the name of R Special Backtick and Parentheses Syntax?

Tags: r, syntax, operators

I have recently encountered the following R syntax:

```
(`::`("ggplot","aes"))()
```

or

```
(`$`(mylist,"column"))
```

I understand what it does, but I struggle to find any documentation on it, as it is quite difficult to search for special characters. Can anyone tell me what this Syntax is called and where I can learn more about it?

Edit: I am NOT asking about the meaning of the operators but about the SYNTAX of putting them in backticks infront of parentheses. I hope that clarifies what I mean.

Using the ? operator in R could not provide me with any useful information. But maybe I did not use it correctly.

Comment: You'll find some doc under `?\`::\`` (double colon operator). The parenthesis syntax is usually referred to as an anonymous function (or lambda function)

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Operators

Comment: @Maël Thank you, I was looking for anonymous/lambda functions!

Comment: It works because the parser translates operators into function calls.

Comment: Backticks are used to call non-syntactic names (see `?Quotes`, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220823/what-do-backticks-do-in-r). The parentheses are used to use the function: check what `\`::\`("ggplot2","aes")` does.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for some info on rewriting functions into prefix form.  See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#prefix-transform

Comment: @RitchieSacramento, post as an answer?

Answer (score -3):

<s>As answered by @Maël, it is referred to as a lambda or anonymous function.</s>

Thanks to the comments of other users, it seems the answer provided my @Maël is not correct. Instead, as suggested by @RitchieSacramento, https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#prefix-transform says:

> An interesting property of R is that every infix, replacement, or
> special form can be rewritten in prefix form. Doing so is useful
> because it helps you better understand the structure of the language,
> it gives you the real name of every function, and it allows you to
> modify those functions for fun and profit.
>
> The following example shows three pairs of equivalent calls, rewriting
> an infix form, replacement form, and a special form into prefix form.
>
> ```
> x + y
> `+`(x, y)
>
> names(df) <- c("x", "y", "z")
> `names<-`(df, c("x", "y", "z"))
>
> for(i in 1:10) print(i)
> `for`(i, 1:10, print(i))
> ```

This provides exactly the explanation that I was looking for and I would advise anyone to checkout the referenced chapter for more info.

Comment: No, that's not correct. The function is not anonymous at all.

Comment: See the comment to your question by @RitchieSacramento to get the actual idea.