# Using scale_colour_manual in ggplot with dynamic names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting lines in R with ggplot() and using scale_colour_manual() to assign names to variables and create a legend. The following is a simple example that works:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  y=c(10,14,13,16,17,14,11,17,19,16),
  z=c(20,15,13,21,18,16,11,14,17,18))
ggplot(df)+ # This works as intended
  geom_line(aes(x,y,colour="Test name 1"))+
  geom_line(aes(x,z,colour="Test name 2"))+
  scale_colour_manual(name="My title",values=c(
    "Test name 1"="red","Test name 2"="blue"))
```

However, I would like to assign the names dynamically, elsewhere in the code. For example,

```
nam1 <- "Test name 1"
nam2 <- "Test name 2"
ggplot(df)+ # This does not work as intended
  geom_line(aes(x,y,colour=nam1))+
  geom_line(aes(x,z,colour=nam2))+
  scale_colour_manual(name="My title",values=c(
    nam1="red",nam2="blue"))
```

When I do it this way, the lines are black and there is no legend. ggplot does not accept a character variable such as nam1 in place of an explicit string such as "Test name 1". How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
nam1 <- "Test name 1"
nam2 <- "Test name 2"
ggplot(df)+ # This does not work as intended
  geom_line(aes(x,y,colour=nam1))+
  geom_line(aes(x,z,colour=nam2))+
  scale_colour_manual(name="My title",values=c("red",
    "blue") |> `names<-`(c(nam1, nam2)))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand why it works, but it does. Thank you!

Comment: @PhilSmith Welcome! The idea is that you create a named vector in two steps. First you create a character vector `tmpvec <- c("red", "blue")` and then assgn names to its memebers: `names(tmpvec) <- c(nam1, nam2)`. The result (`myvec`) is passed as `values` argument of `scale_colour_manual()`. All is done without explicit `tmpvec` assgnment and in a pipe.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is clear, but I remain puzzled about the use of back-ticks in `names<-`.

Comment: @PhilSmith I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36221371/5043424) might be useful to explain what backticks can be used for.