Plotting time series in R using ggplot
I have a data frame with two columns.  It the first is the time of data a request was made in hours:minutes:seconds format.  The second column contains the number of minutes it took to complete the request.
when I use 'plot()' in base R, it gives me a basic scatter plot without issue.  When I try to put it into ggplot I get the following:
"Warning: \[38;5;250mAll aesthetics have length 1, but the data has 87 rows. \[36mℹ\[38;5;250m Did you mean to use \`annotate()\`?\[39m".

It does display a plot, but it is just two axis with a single point.
I have placed the data frame into the dput() function and pasted the output below
structure(list(`Order Time` = structure(c(-2209067733, -2208991620, 
-2209031808, -2209025030, -2209022501, -2209006936, -2209007168, 
-2209027968, -2209035932, -2209028941, -2209004948, -2209070934, 
-2209030418, -2209018856, -2209018041, -2209041405, -2209055940, 
-2209024891, -2209054157, -2209007145, -2208989104, -2209023868, 
-2209065315, -2208996091, -2209016728, -2209045016, -2209022746, 
-2209008132, -2209020141, -2209003186, -2209023453, -2209037310, 
-2208994122, -2209017969, -2209048043, -2209019289, -2209068394, 
-2209045114, -2208994213, -2209039028, -2209016558, -2209013258, 
-2209059017, -2208999105, -2209030858, -2209005507, -2209004852, 
-2208997739, -2209017292, -2209027275, -2209002050, -2209002360, 
-2209018231, -2209028904, -2209023644, -2208990474, -2209000518, 
-2208993688, -2209021437, -2209018324, -2208990042, -2209041306, 
-2209015105, -2208990091, -2209074416, -2209045786, -2209001815, 
-2209005009, -2209017487, -2208991033, -2209068840, -2209012408, 
-2209039642, -2209014277, -2209074441, -2209065490, -2209064888, 
-2209025754, -2209003145, -2209009233, -2209031908, -2209025111, 
-2209014456, -2208997047, -2209039772, -2209068463, -2209055958
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Order to Final (min)` = c(311, 
112, 105, 18, 78, 50, 64, 60, 25, 238, 47, 85, 161, 78, 87, 51, 
221, 86, 170, 93, 145, 53, 56, 31, 83, 63, 86, 177, 28, 71, 72, 
40, 58, 89, 71, 40, 281, 75, 11, 70, 80, 71, 131, 108, 46, 53, 
83, 31, 43, 35, 46, 168, 42, 132, 149, 100, 154, 61, 75, 49, 
157, 56, 60, 224, 56, 55, 70, 220, 59, 145, 102, 79, 96, 423, 
67, 834, 233, 35, 87, 52, 31, 103, 50, 108, 192, 135, 56)), row.names = c(NA, 
-87L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

This is using 'plot(time_frame$hms, time_frame$`Order to Final (min)`)' which is what I would like to get out of ggplot
I am trying to use ggplot to plot this as a scatter plot:
ggplot(time_frame, aes( 'Order Time', 'Order to Final (min)')) + geom_point()


What is your code?

ggplot(time_frame, aes( 'Order Time',  'Order to Final (min)')) + geom_point()

Use backticks or better use janitor::clean_names()

Related: Difference between backticks and quotes in aes function in ggplot

Backticks vs. ticks. With ticks, 'Order Time` is interpreted as "a character string of length one that is that phrase", vs. with backticks R interprets it as the name of a column within the time_frame data frame.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229703/6851825
ggplot(time_frame, aes(`Order Time`, `Order to Final (min)`)) + geom_point() 



Thanks. That is helpful as well.  I think I will use the Janitor package one of the other folks pointed out in the future to clean those up.  It plots very nicely now.

It is suggested to use janitor::clean_names() whenever there are unclean column names in data so as to avoid confusion between using backtick in lieu of single quote.
df <- structure(list(`Order Time` = structure(c(-2209067733, -2208991620, 
                                                -2209031808, -2209025030, -2209022501, -2209006936, -2209007168, 
                                                -2209027968, -2209035932, -2209028941, -2209004948, -2209070934, 
                                                -2209030418, -2209018856, -2209018041, -2209041405, -2209055940, 
                                                -2209024891, -2209054157, -2209007145, -2208989104, -2209023868, 
                                                -2209065315, -2208996091, -2209016728, -2209045016, -2209022746, 
                                                -2209008132, -2209020141, -2209003186, -2209023453, -2209037310, 
                                                -2208994122, -2209017969, -2209048043, -2209019289, -2209068394, 
                                                -2209045114, -2208994213, -2209039028, -2209016558, -2209013258, 
                                                -2209059017, -2208999105, -2209030858, -2209005507, -2209004852, 
                                                -2208997739, -2209017292, -2209027275, -2209002050, -2209002360, 
                                                -2209018231, -2209028904, -2209023644, -2208990474, -2209000518, 
                                                -2208993688, -2209021437, -2209018324, -2208990042, -2209041306, 
                                                -2209015105, -2208990091, -2209074416, -2209045786, -2209001815, 
                                                -2209005009, -2209017487, -2208991033, -2209068840, -2209012408, 
                                                -2209039642, -2209014277, -2209074441, -2209065490, -2209064888, 
                                                -2209025754, -2209003145, -2209009233, -2209031908, -2209025111, 
                                                -2209014456, -2208997047, -2209039772, -2209068463, -2209055958
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `Order to Final (min)` = c(311, 
                                                                              112, 105, 18, 78, 50, 64, 60, 25, 238, 47, 85, 161, 78, 87, 51, 
                                                                              221, 86, 170, 93, 145, 53, 56, 31, 83, 63, 86, 177, 28, 71, 72, 
                                                                              40, 58, 89, 71, 40, 281, 75, 11, 70, 80, 71, 131, 108, 46, 53, 
                                                                              83, 31, 43, 35, 46, 168, 42, 132, 149, 100, 154, 61, 75, 49, 
                                                                              157, 56, 60, 224, 56, 55, 70, 220, 59, 145, 102, 79, 96, 423, 
                                                                              67, 834, 233, 35, 87, 52, 31, 103, 50, 108, 192, 135, 56)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                        -87L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(order_time, order_to_final_min)) +
  geom_point()


Created on 2024-04-08 with reprex v2.1.0
